Accuracy of the Higuera-Cary Particle Pusher
UPDATE: 12 July 2024
This question has been answered. Also, I figured out the problem. One of the papers I was referencing (Ripperda et al.) had a typo, which was leading to the errors. The method is working fine now.
ORIGINAL QUESTION
I am currently working on the comparison of particle pushers and using a custom-built code to check the accuracy of three major particle pushers relevant to the field of relativistic plasma simulations.
One of these methods is the Higuera-Cary integrator, proposed by A. V. Higuera, and J.R. Cary at this link. In this paper, the authors claim that their integrator both preserves volume and also gives the correct cross-field drift velocity ($\vec{E} \times \vec{B}$ drift). The accuracy of this integrator is visible in the phase-space plot that the authors have shown in their paper. Further, Ripperda et al. have also written an excellent paper on the comparison of relativistic particle pushers where they showcase the excellent accuracy of this pusher. This is available at this link.
Here is where my problem comes in. I have repeatedly checked my code but I am getting huge errors when using the Higuera-Cary integrator to perform single-particle simulations. These errors go as high as 100%. For reference, I am attaching configuration space plot here:

The simulation parameters are as follows:
$$dt = 5\times 10^{-12}$$
$$\vec{B} = 5 \hat{k}$$
$$\vec{E} = \vec{0}$$
$$\vec{v} = (0.58 \hat{i} + 1.0002 \hat{j} + 2.766 \hat{k}) \times 10^8$$
As can be seen, the analytical plot, the Boris plot, and the Vay plot overlap almost completely and no difference is even visible. However, the Higuera-Cary method shows insane inaccuracies and undergoes spurious acceleration.
My questions are as follows:

Has anyone here used the Higuera-Cary method directly? What was your experience?
Is there any established open-source program that uses this method?
Is there any specific reference I must look into?
Although I have repeatedly checked my own code, I cannot find anything wrong with it. Is it possible that the error lies within the Higuera-Cary method itself?


In the 2nd link (i.e., https://doi.org/10.3847/1538-4365/aab114), it's difficult to see but the HC method does seem to have larger errors in position of a particle but smaller in other parameters (e.g., phase lag).  In Figure 2, they have to remove some offset, which doesn't make sense to me.  How can a method have an offset like that if it's supposed to be accurate?  The offset is five orders of magnitude larger than the errors for the other methods, for reference.  That's a huge difference!  I know Sironi and Lapenta and trust both so this paper is likely correct.

Unfortunately, Giovanni Lapenta recently passed away :(

@honeste_vivere It looks like the article says the offset in Fig 2 is due to the leapfrog scheme incorrectly estimating the position of the first step in that specific test. They repeated the test with the analytically-computed position and get the better results.

@KyleKanos - Ah okay, thanks.  I assumed there was a decent reason but didn't have the time to dig into the paper too much.



Is there any established open-source program that uses this method?


Yes. You even link an article that uses it: Keppens' MPI-AMRVAC is available on github. It even includes the HC integrator in the Lorentz integrator file.
A mild forewarning: like the original AMRVAC, the parallelized version is also written in Fortran 90 but in a dimension-independent manner using preprocessing. It can be a little disorienting/confusing when reading much of the code due to the vectorized commands that are obscured by the specialized syntax. That said, the particle files don't seem to be too impacted by this.
I haven't done a deep read through of the code and paper, but equations (9)-(22) describing the three particle pushers do seem to line up exactly with the code.
If you prefer C++, there is also picFOAM that also has an implementation of the HC integrator.


Although I have repeatedly checked my own code, I cannot find anything wrong with it. Is it possible that the error lies within the Higuera-Cary method itself?


It is highly unlikely that the dozens of papers referencing the HC paper would find it not problematic while you do. Far more likely is there is indeed a hidden bug or error in your code.

Ah yes. Thank you. I was actually looking for some C++ implementation only since despite my sincerest efforts, Fortran seems to go well above my head. Let me check out picFOAM. Much obliged to you once again.
